# Subtract inputted list infinitely with appending if necessary. #Sequence Identifier

Tags: python

```
#Sample Code

list = [input()]
#I want it to subtract the 2nd term from the first term. The third term 
from the second term. And so on and so forth until they have the same 
difference. How can I run it until infinity?
```

[Here is the photo of my problem.
General Sequence Formula creator. However, I want a program that will identify if there is a sequence even '5 to be inputted list' are given. PS. I'm not good in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZBxG.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the challenge. I solved this with recursion meaning that it will continue until it finds the Sequence Identifier.

```py
def findSequenceIdentifier(data):
    if len(set(data)) <= 1: return data
    
    output = []
    
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i == len(data)-1: return findSequenceIdentifier(output)
        
        difference = max(data[i], data[i+1]) - min(data[i], data[i+1])
        
        output.append(difference)
```

This will return the final list of differences, i.e. in your examples if the input is `[1,4,9,16,25]` it will return `[2,2,2]`.